# IIS Rewrite - Redirect only home page URL only - not deep links

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I have a business requirement to redirect the browsing attempts to Home page URL only to a different site, deep URLs however should not be redirected.

eg. mydomain.com/**abc** should go to mydomain.com/**XYZ**

BUT

mydomain.com/**abc**/deep/page.html etc should remain untouched.

## I have a windows server with IIS7. I tried HTTP redirect, but it redirects all calls (home or deep) from abc to xyz.

Upon advise from Lex li, added the following rewrite rule, it tested positive in IIS but is not redirecting during actual browsing:

```xml
<rules>
  <rule name="iamNoSlash" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="abc$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="mydomain.com/xyz" appendQueryString="false" />
  </rule>
  <rule name="iamWithSlash">
    <match url="abc/$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="mydomain.com/xyz" appendQueryString="false" /> 
  </rule>
</rules>
```

Comment: Please switch to IIS URL Rewrite module. Then make sure your regular expression in URL rewrite rule only capture `abc` or `abc/` and I don't think that's something hard.

Comment: I added he following rewrite rule, it tested positive in IIS but is not redirecting during actual browsing:
  <rules>
                <rule name="iamNoSlash" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="abc$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="mydomain.com/xyz" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="iamWithSlash">
                    <match url="abc/$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="mydomain.com/xyz" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>

Comment: Edit your question to include the rule and well format it please. No one should see it ugly in the comment.